# dojox.validate.check Validation - set up profile

Tags: dojo

When using dojox.validate.check (form, profile), we have to set up the profile variable

What is the right format for postalCode isNumberFormat?  I want to set up so that I can validate according to this format (#####-####).  I've tried different way to set it up but I didn't have much success.

var profile = {

```
required: [ "postalCode" ],
constraints: {
    postalCode: dojox.validate.isNumberFormat (How do I set up here)
}
```

}

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

```
required: [ "postalCode" ],
constraints: {
postalCode: [ dojox.validate.isNumberFormat, {format:["#####-####"]}]
}
```